# What is the computational complexity category of $T(n) = m^{\frac{n-1}{m}}$?

Tags: terminology, asymptotics

I'm analyzing the computational complexity of an algorithm whose input size is $n$. Finally, I've ended up with 
$T(n) = {m^\frac{n-1}{m}}$ where $m$ is a constant. Can one explain the type name corresponding to this computational complexity (e.g., exponential, etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $c=m^{\frac{1}{m}}$ is a constant, your $T(n) = c^{n-1} \in \Theta(c^n)$ is simply exponential.